# Visitor methods for Java grammar not working in ANTLR 4.4

Tags: java, grammar, antlr4

I am new to ANTLR framework. I have been working around this for a week.
Now am in a situation where i need to parse the Java file and extract the data.
Am using ANTLR 4 for parsing. I create the Lexer, Parser and Visitor files using ANTLR in built tool.
When I try to over ride the Visitor method I doesn't gets  called and returns `null` value.

Here is the coding.

I have generated `JavaLexer, JavaParser, JavaVisitor, JavaBaseVisitor, JavaListener`

```
package com.antlr;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.*;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.*;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;


public class ExtractInterfaceVisitor {


    public  static class AnnVisitor extends JavaBaseVisitor<String> {

        @Override
        public String visitAnnotation (JavaParser.AnnotationContext ctx) 
        {
            System.out.println("Annotation");
            return ctx.getText();
         }

@Override
 public String visitClassDeclaration( JavaParser.ClassDeclarationContext ctx)
 {

     System.out.println("Class Declaration");
     return ctx.getText(); 
 }
 }


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
   String inputFile = null;
   inputFile =  "C:/Users/User/Desktop/antlr/java1/Demo.java"; //Contains a Java File
   InputStream is = System.in;
   is = new FileInputStream(inputFile);

   ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(is);
   JavaLexer lexer = new JavaLexer(input);
   CommonTokenStream tokens = new CommonTokenStream(lexer);
   JavaParser parser = new JavaParser(tokens);
   parser.setBuildParseTree(true);      // tell ANTLR to build a parse tree
   ParseTree tree = parser.compilationUnit(); // parse
   // show tree in text form
   //System.out.println(tree.toStringTree(parser));

   AnnVisitor Visitor = new AnnVisitor();
   String result = Visitor.visit(tree);
   System.out.println("visitor result = "+result);
    }
}
```

Demo.java

```
@ClassAnnotation(Value="Class")
public class Demo {

    @MethodAnnotation(Value="Method")
    void MethodName(int x, String y) {  }
    int x;

    int[ ] g(/*no args*/)
    {   }

    int average()
    {   }

    List<Map<String, Integer>>[] h() { return null; }
}
```

Java.g4

```
/** Java 1.6 grammar (ANTLR v4). Derived from

    http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf

    and JavaParser.g from ANTLR v3
 */
grammar Java;

@lexer::members {
  protected boolean enumIsKeyword = true;
  protected boolean assertIsKeyword = true;
}

// starting point for parsing a java file
compilationUnit
    :   packageDeclaration? importDeclaration* typeDeclaration*
        EOF
    ;

packageDeclaration
    :   'package' qualifiedName ';'
    ;

importDeclaration
    :   'import' 'static'? qualifiedName ('.' '*')? ';'
    ;

typeDeclaration
    :   classOrInterfaceModifier*
        (   classDeclaration
        |   interfaceDeclaration
        |   enumDeclaration
        )
    |   ';'
    ;

classDeclaration
    :   'class' Identifier typeParameters? ('extends' type)?
        ('implements' typeList)?
        classBody
    ;

enumDeclaration
    :   ENUM Identifier ('implements' typeList)? enumBody
    ;

interfaceDeclaration
    :   normalInterfaceDeclaration
    |   annotationTypeDeclaration
    ;

classOrInterfaceModifier
    :   annotation   // class or interface
    |   'public'     // class or interface
    |   'protected'  // class or interface
    |   'private'    // class or interface
    |   'abstract'   // class or interface
    |   'static'     // class or interface
    |   'final'      // class only -- does not apply to interfaces
    |   'strictfp'   // class or interface
    ;

modifiers
    :   modifier*
    ;

typeParameters
    :   '<' typeParameter (',' typeParameter)* '>'
    ;

typeParameter
    :   Identifier ('extends' typeBound)?
    ;

typeBound
    :   type ('&' type)*
    ;

enumBody
    :   '{' enumConstants? ','? enumBodyDeclarations? '}'
    ;

enumConstants
    :   enumConstant (',' enumConstant)*
    ;

enumConstant
    :   annotations? Identifier arguments? classBody?
    ;

enumBodyDeclarations
    :   ';' (classBodyDeclaration)*
    ;

normalInterfaceDeclaration
    :   'interface' Identifier typeParameters? ('extends' typeList)? interfaceBody
    ;

typeList
    :   type (',' type)*
    ;

classBody
    :   '{' classBodyDeclaration* '}'
    ;

interfaceBody
    :   '{' interfaceBodyDeclaration* '}'
    ;

classBodyDeclaration
    :   ';'
    |   'static'? block
    |   modifiers member
    ;

member
    :   genericMethodDeclaration
    |   methodDeclaration
    |   fieldDeclaration
    |   constructorDeclaration
    |   interfaceDeclaration
    |   classDeclaration
    ;

methodDeclaration
    :   type Identifier formalParameters ('[' ']')* methodDeclarationRest
    |   'void' Identifier formalParameters methodDeclarationRest
    ;

methodDeclarationRest
    :   ('throws' qualifiedNameList)?
        (   methodBody
        |   ';'
        )
    ;

genericMethodDeclaration
    :   typeParameters methodDeclaration
    ;

fieldDeclaration
    :   type variableDeclarators ';'
    ;

constructorDeclaration
    :   typeParameters? Identifier formalParameters
        ('throws' qualifiedNameList)? constructorBody
    ;

interfaceBodyDeclaration
    :   modifiers interfaceMemberDecl
    |   ';'
    ;

interfaceMemberDecl
    :   interfaceMethodOrFieldDecl
    |   interfaceGenericMethodDecl
    |   'void' Identifier voidInterfaceMethodDeclaratorRest
    |   interfaceDeclaration
    |   classDeclaration
    ;

interfaceMethodOrFieldDecl
    :   type Identifier interfaceMethodOrFieldRest
    ;

interfaceMethodOrFieldRest
    :   constantDeclaratorsRest ';'
    |   interfaceMethodDeclaratorRest
    ;

voidMethodDeclaratorRest
    :   formalParameters ('throws' qualifiedNameList)?
        (   methodBody
        |   ';'
        )
    ;

interfaceMethodDeclaratorRest
    :   formalParameters ('[' ']')* ('throws' qualifiedNameList)? ';'
    ;

interfaceGenericMethodDecl
    :   typeParameters (type | 'void') Identifier
        interfaceMethodDeclaratorRest
    ;

voidInterfaceMethodDeclaratorRest
    :   formalParameters ('throws' qualifiedNameList)? ';'
    ;

constantDeclarator
    :   Identifier constantDeclaratorRest
    ;

variableDeclarators
    :   variableDeclarator (',' variableDeclarator)*
    ;

variableDeclarator
    :   variableDeclaratorId ('=' variableInitializer)?
    ;

constantDeclaratorsRest
    :   constantDeclaratorRest (',' constantDeclarator)*
    ;

constantDeclaratorRest
    :   ('[' ']')* '=' variableInitializer
    ;

variableDeclaratorId
    :   Identifier ('[' ']')*
    ;

variableInitializer
    :   arrayInitializer
    |   expression
    ;

arrayInitializer
    :   '{' (variableInitializer (',' variableInitializer)* (',')? )? '}'
    ;

modifier
    :   annotation
    |   'public'
    |   'protected'
    |   'private'
    |   'static'
    |   'abstract'
    |   'final'
    |   'native'
    |   'synchronized'
    |   'transient'
    |   'volatile'
    |   'strictfp'
    ;

packageOrTypeName
    :   qualifiedName
    ;

enumConstantName
    :   Identifier
    ;

typeName
    :   qualifiedName
    ;

type:   classOrInterfaceType ('[' ']')*
    |   primitiveType ('[' ']')*
    ;

classOrInterfaceType
    :   Identifier typeArguments? ('.' Identifier typeArguments? )*
    ;

primitiveType
    :   'boolean'
    |   'char'
    |   'byte'
    |   'short'
    |   'int'
    |   'long'
    |   'float'
    |   'double'
    ;

variableModifier
    :   'final'
    |   annotation
    ;

typeArguments
    :   '<' typeArgument (',' typeArgument)* '>'
    ;

typeArgument
    :   type
    |   '?' (('extends' | 'super') type)?
    ;

qualifiedNameList
    :   qualifiedName (',' qualifiedName)*
    ;

formalParameters
    :   '(' formalParameterDecls? ')'
    ;

formalParameterDecls
    :   variableModifiers type formalParameterDeclsRest
    ;

formalParameterDeclsRest
    :   variableDeclaratorId (',' formalParameterDecls)?
    |   '...' variableDeclaratorId
    ;

methodBody
    :   block
    ;

constructorBody
    :   '{' explicitConstructorInvocation? blockStatement* '}'
    ;

explicitConstructorInvocation
    :   nonWildcardTypeArguments? ('this' | 'super') arguments ';'
    |   primary '.' nonWildcardTypeArguments? 'super' arguments ';'
    ;

qualifiedName
    :   Identifier ('.' Identifier)*
    ;

literal
    :   integerLiteral
    |   FloatingPointLiteral
    |   CharacterLiteral
    |   StringLiteral
    |   booleanLiteral
    |   'null'
    ;

integerLiteral
    :   HexLiteral
    |   OctalLiteral
    |   DecimalLiteral
    ;

booleanLiteral
    :   'true'
    |   'false'
    ;

// ANNOTATIONS

annotations
    :   annotation+
    ;

annotation
    :   '@' annotationName ( '(' ( elementValuePairs | elementValue )? ')' )?
    ;

annotationName
    : Identifier ('.' Identifier)*
    ;

elementValuePairs
    :   elementValuePair (',' elementValuePair)*
    ;

elementValuePair
    :   Identifier '=' elementValue
    ;

elementValue
    :   expression
    |   annotation
    |   elementValueArrayInitializer
    ;

elementValueArrayInitializer
    :   '{' (elementValue (',' elementValue)*)? (',')? '}'
    ;

annotationTypeDeclaration
    :   '@' 'interface' Identifier annotationTypeBody
    ;

annotationTypeBody
    :   '{' (annotationTypeElementDeclaration)* '}'
    ;

annotationTypeElementDeclaration
    :   modifiers annotationTypeElementRest
    ;

annotationTypeElementRest
    :   type annotationMethodOrConstantRest ';'
    |   classDeclaration ';'?
    |   normalInterfaceDeclaration ';'?
    |   enumDeclaration ';'?
    |   annotationTypeDeclaration ';'?
    ;

annotationMethodOrConstantRest
    :   annotationMethodRest
    |   annotationConstantRest
    ;

annotationMethodRest
    :   Identifier '(' ')' defaultValue?
    ;

annotationConstantRest
    :   variableDeclarators
    ;

defaultValue
    :   'default' elementValue
    ;

// STATEMENTS / BLOCKS

block
    :   '{' blockStatement* '}'
    ;

blockStatement
    :   localVariableDeclarationStatement
    |   classDeclaration
    |   interfaceDeclaration
    |   statement
    ;

localVariableDeclarationStatement
    :    localVariableDeclaration ';'
    ;

localVariableDeclaration
    :   variableModifiers type variableDeclarators
    ;

variableModifiers
    :   variableModifier*
    ;

statement
    : block
    |   ASSERT expression (':' expression)? ';'
    |   'if' parExpression statement ('else' statement)?
    |   'for' '(' forControl ')' statement
    |   'while' parExpression statement
    |   'do' statement 'while' parExpression ';'
    |   'try' block
        ( catches 'finally' block
        | catches
        | 'finally' block
        )
    |   'switch' parExpression switchBlock
    |   'synchronized' parExpression block
    |   'return' expression? ';'
    |   'throw' expression ';'
    |   'break' Identifier? ';'
    |   'continue' Identifier? ';'
    |   ';'
    |   statementExpression ';'
    |   Identifier ':' statement
    ;

catches
    :   catchClause (catchClause)*
    ;

catchClause
    :   'catch' '(' formalParameter ')' block
    ;

formalParameter
    :   variableModifiers type variableDeclaratorId
    ;

switchBlock
    :   '{' switchBlockStatementGroup* switchLabel* '}'
    ;

switchBlockStatementGroup
    :   switchLabel+ blockStatement*
    ;

switchLabel
    :   'case' constantExpression ':'
    |   'case' enumConstantName ':'
    |   'default' ':'
    ;

forControl
    :   enhancedForControl
    |   forInit? ';' expression? ';' forUpdate?
    ;

forInit
    :   localVariableDeclaration
    |   expressionList
    ;

enhancedForControl
    :   variableModifiers type Identifier ':' expression
    ;

forUpdate
    :   expressionList
    ;

// EXPRESSIONS

parExpression
    :   '(' expression ')'
    ;

expressionList
    :   expression (',' expression)*
    ;

statementExpression
    :   expression
    ;

constantExpression
    :   expression
    ;

expression
    :   primary
    |   expression '.' Identifier
    |   expression '.' 'this'
    |   expression '.' 'super' '(' expressionList? ')'
    |   expression '.' 'new' Identifier '(' expressionList? ')'
    |   expression '.' 'super' '.' Identifier arguments?
    |   expression '.' explicitGenericInvocation
    |   expression '[' expression ']'
    |   expression '(' expressionList? ')'
    |   expression ('++' | '--')
    |   ('+'|'-'|'++'|'--') expression
    |   ('~'|'!') expression
    |   '(' type ')' expression
    |   'new' creator
    |   expression ('*'|'/'|'%') expression
    |   expression ('+'|'-') expression
    |   expression ('<' '<' | '>' '>' '>' | '>' '>') expression
    |   expression ('<' '=' | '>' '=' | '>' | '<') expression
    |   expression 'instanceof' type
    |   expression ('==' | '!=') expression
    |   expression '&' expression
    |   expression '^' expression
    |   expression '|' expression
    |   expression '&&' expression
    |   expression '||' expression
    |   expression '?' expression ':' expression
    |   expression
        ('^='<assoc=right>
        |'+='<assoc=right>
        |'-='<assoc=right>
        |'*='<assoc=right>
        |'/='<assoc=right>
        |'&='<assoc=right>
        |'|='<assoc=right>
        |'='<assoc=right>
        |'>' '>' '='<assoc=right>
        |'>' '>' '>' '='<assoc=right>
        |'<' '<' '='<assoc=right>
        |'%='<assoc=right>
        )
        expression
    ;

primary
    :   '(' expression ')'
    |   'this'
    |   'super'
    |   literal
    |   Identifier
    |   type '.' 'class'
    |   'void' '.' 'class'
    ;

creator
    :   nonWildcardTypeArguments createdName classCreatorRest
    |   createdName (arrayCreatorRest | classCreatorRest)
    ;

createdName
    :   classOrInterfaceType
    |   primitiveType
    ;

innerCreator
    :   nonWildcardTypeArguments? Identifier classCreatorRest
    ;

explicitGenericInvocation
    :   nonWildcardTypeArguments Identifier arguments
    ;

arrayCreatorRest
    :   '['
        (   ']' ('[' ']')* arrayInitializer
        |   expression ']' ('[' expression ']')* ('[' ']')*
        )
    ;

classCreatorRest
    :   arguments classBody?
    ;

nonWildcardTypeArguments
    :   '<' typeList '>'
    ;

arguments
    :   '(' expressionList? ')'
    ;

// LEXER

HexLiteral : '0' ('x'|'X') HexDigit+ IntegerTypeSuffix? ;

DecimalLiteral : ('0' | '1'..'9' '0'..'9'*) IntegerTypeSuffix? ;

OctalLiteral : '0' ('0'..'7')+ IntegerTypeSuffix? ;

fragment
HexDigit : ('0'..'9'|'a'..'f'|'A'..'F') ;

fragment
IntegerTypeSuffix : ('l'|'L') ;

FloatingPointLiteral
    :   ('0'..'9')+ '.' ('0'..'9')* Exponent? FloatTypeSuffix?
    |   '.' ('0'..'9')+ Exponent? FloatTypeSuffix?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ Exponent FloatTypeSuffix?
    |   ('0'..'9')+ FloatTypeSuffix
    |   ('0x' | '0X') (HexDigit )*
        ('.' (HexDigit)*)?
        ( 'p' | 'P' )
        ( '+' | '-' )?
        ( '0' .. '9' )+
        FloatTypeSuffix?
    ;

fragment
Exponent : ('e'|'E') ('+'|'-')? ('0'..'9')+ ;

fragment
FloatTypeSuffix : ('f'|'F'|'d'|'D') ;

CharacterLiteral
    :   '\'' ( EscapeSequence | ~('\''|'\\') ) '\''
    ;

StringLiteral
    :  '"' ( EscapeSequence | ~('\\'|'"') )* '"'
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
    :   '\\' ('b'|'t'|'n'|'f'|'r'|'\"'|'\''|'\\')
    |   UnicodeEscape
    |   OctalEscape
    ;

fragment
OctalEscape
    :   '\\' ('0'..'3') ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7') ('0'..'7')
    |   '\\' ('0'..'7')
    ;

fragment
UnicodeEscape
    :   '\\' 'u' HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit
    ;

ENUM:   'enum' {if (!enumIsKeyword) setType(Identifier);}
    ;

ASSERT
    :   'assert' {if (!assertIsKeyword) setType(Identifier);}
    ;

Identifier
    :   Letter (Letter|JavaIDDigit)*
    ;

/**I found this char range in JavaCC's grammar, but Letter and Digit overlap.
   Still works, but...
 */
fragment
Letter
    :  '\u0024' |
       '\u0041'..'\u005a' |
       '\u005f' |
       '\u0061'..'\u007a' |
       '\u00c0'..'\u00d6' |
       '\u00d8'..'\u00f6' |
       '\u00f8'..'\u00ff' |
       '\u0100'..'\u1fff' |
       '\u3040'..'\u318f' |
       '\u3300'..'\u337f' |
       '\u3400'..'\u3d2d' |
       '\u4e00'..'\u9fff' |
       '\uf900'..'\ufaff'
    ;

fragment
JavaIDDigit
    :  '\u0030'..'\u0039' |
       '\u0660'..'\u0669' |
       '\u06f0'..'\u06f9' |
       '\u0966'..'\u096f' |
       '\u09e6'..'\u09ef' |
       '\u0a66'..'\u0a6f' |
       '\u0ae6'..'\u0aef' |
       '\u0b66'..'\u0b6f' |
       '\u0be7'..'\u0bef' |
       '\u0c66'..'\u0c6f' |
       '\u0ce6'..'\u0cef' |
       '\u0d66'..'\u0d6f' |
       '\u0e50'..'\u0e59' |
       '\u0ed0'..'\u0ed9' |
       '\u1040'..'\u1049'
   ;

COMMENT
    :   '/*' .*? '*/'    -> channel(HIDDEN) // match anything between /* and */
    ;
WS  :   [ \r\t\u000C\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;

LINE_COMMENT
    : '//' ~[\r\n]* '\r'? '\n' -> channel(HIDDEN)
    ;
```

The Final out put which i get is:  `Visitor result = null`

I don't know where i went wrong. It doesn't call the visit methods also. Please correct me.

Comment: you may find this useful http://leonotepad.blogspot.com.br/2014/01/playing-with-antlr4-primefaces.html

Comment: Thanks you! but can u plz say y my visit methods are not getting executed?

Comment: I am exactly facing the same issue right now. Have you found solution to this problem?

Answer (score 7):

The generated parse tree visitor extends [AbstractParseTreeVisitor](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/runtime/Java/src/org/antlr/v4/runtime/tree/AbstractParseTreeVisitor.java), which has two methods which would be helpful to override to get the result you are looking for.

Firstly, `AbstractParseTreeVisitor#defaultResult()` returns the default result for every node in the parse tree you visit. By default, it returns `null`.

Second, `AbstractParseTreeVisitor#aggregateResult(T,T)` aggregates the last node's visited result with the total result so far.

You have not overridden either of these methods, so aggregateResult(T,T) is returning the default result of the last parse tree node visited, which is giving you a `null` result.

So, if you want to fix this, I would override `defaultResult` to look something like this:

```
@Override
public String aggregateResult(String aggregate, String nextResult) {
    if (aggregate == null) {
        return nextResult;
    }

    if (nextResult == null) {
        return aggregrate;
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(aggregate);
    sb.append(" ");
    sb.append(nextResult);

    return sb.toString();
}
```

If you don't want to do the null checks in your `aggregateResult` override, you could override `defaultResult` to return the empty String and then have `aggregateResult` append every result to the aggregate, but I personally prefer the first solution.

Comment: Thanks! should v override aggregateResult() or defaultResult() ?

Comment: @Narayana It depends on what your implementation is. Sounds like you can get by with just overriding aggregate result. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! if u don mind can u post the working coding. I tried but again getting the same output sir!\

Comment: `AbstractParseTreeVisitor` is one of the better documented classes in the ANTLR 4 runtime IMO. Disclaimer: I wrote that class.

Comment: @280Z28 oh! thats great sir! can u please explain. Should I override visitChildren() also? kindly go through my code and correct me.

Comment: What I need to do is: read a annotation and match its value to a variable according to the annotation name. @ClassName(Value="xxx") this should be matched with a variable "className" (of another class) and it should b assigned value as xxx. is this possible?

Comment: The Antlr4 reference (dated 2012) does not mention "aggregateResult" or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

I also used ANTLR before but I ended up using Eclipse JDT is updated for JAVA8 and its really simple to get started with the AST.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.AST;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTParser;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.CompilationUnit;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MarkerAnnotation;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.NormalAnnotation;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SimpleName;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.SingleMemberAnnotation;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.VariableDeclarationFragment;

/**
 *
 * @author Lethe
 */
public class Parser {

    public Parser() {
    }

    public String readFile(String path, Charset encoding)
            throws IOException {
        byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
        return new String(encoded, encoding);
    }

    public void parseSource() {

        try {
            ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
            String source = readFile("test.java", Charset.defaultCharset());
            //parser.setSource("public class A { int i = 9;  \n int j; \n ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();j=1000; }".toCharArray());
            parser.setSource(source.toCharArray());
            parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
            //ASTNode node = parser.createAST(null);

            final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

            cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {

                Set names = new HashSet();

                public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
                    SimpleName name = node.getName();
                    this.names.add(name.getIdentifier());
                    System.out.println("Declaration of '" + name + "' at line" + cu.getLineNumber(name.getStartPosition()));
                    return false; // do not continue to avoid usage info
                }

                public boolean visit(SimpleName node) {
                    if (this.names.contains(node.getIdentifier())) {
                        System.out.println("Usage of '" + node + "' at line " + cu.getLineNumber(node.getStartPosition()));
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                public boolean visit(SingleMemberAnnotation annotation) {
                    System.out.println(annotation.getTypeName());
                    System.out.println(annotation.getValue());
                    return true;
                }

                public boolean visit(NormalAnnotation annotation) {
                    System.out.println(annotation.getTypeName());
                    return true;
                }

                public boolean visit(MarkerAnnotation annotation) {
                    System.out.println(annotation.getTypeName());
                    return true;
                }

            });
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Parser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps with your AST http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/apt/index.php ^_^

Comment: Thanks for ur answer! Can u please give the answer in ANTLR. i need to work with that only.

Comment: Ya i understand. But in my company v need to use only ANTLR :(

Answer (score 0):

First some advice:

1. You should check out *the definitive antlr reference*. One week is enough of time for that. In there, it says and I quote

"*Visitors  walk  parse  trees  by  explicitly  calling  interface ParseTreeVisitor’s visit()
method on child nodes.*"

2. The class "ExtractInterfaceVisitor" is quite redundant, since You only have one inner class inside of it...
3. Try debugging the code, put breakpoints in your visit methods and see what happens. Chances are that only top-level-rule visitor will be executed.

If You don't see the output "Class Declaration", I could only assume that Demo.java does not start with a class declaration.

EDIT: The first visit method that is called is the one corresponding to the parser rule that matches the first line in Demo.java.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply! Demo.java does start with a class declaration. I was go throughing that book for the past 1 week sir. could so plz help me. I dono y my visitor methods are not called. I tried with sample examples. it was working fine. but not java grammar! :(

Comment: Have You tried setting the breakpoint in visitClassDeclaration? Does it ever get called? Aslo, is compilationUnit Your top-level rule?

Comment: I put a print statement compilationUnit. It didnt get executed.
Any help?

Comment: If You could please post (maybe in the original question) complete files: grammar, redefined visitor, "main" class, and the input file.

Comment: Ya sure.. wait i ll upload!

Comment: Ok,so as I originally assumed the Demo.java **does not** start with a class declaration, but rather with @ClassAnnotation(Value="Class"). Please pay more attention to the questions people ask you. The first visitor that is called is the one for the parser rule corresponding to the aforementioned annotation. My original answer stands. All visitors must explicitly visit child nodes.

Comment: ya! but that follows Java's structure?
May i know y the visitor methods are not getting executed. I generated the remaining Lexer, Parser, Visitor and BaseVisitor using the org.antlr.v4.Tool

Comment: Of course it's "Java's structure" but we are talking here about parsing!It's important to know which parser rule matches the first line of the input file, since that is the first corresponding visitor that is called! Also, if I mentioned 2x that all visitors must visit children nodes (just look at generated BaseVisitor code) than isn't it clear enough? Please just try and debug...

Comment: public String visitAnnotation(JavaParser.AnnotationContext ctx) {
System.out.println("Ann Name"); return visitChildren(ctx);} Since Annotation is the first method that gets executed i explicitly called visitChildren(ctx) but again am getting the same output. kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the exact same issue on Eclipse Neon and I resolved it in the following way.

Step1: I removed Antlr4 sdk from eclipse. This is a plugin to auto generate Visitor and Listener classes after parsing Java.g4 grammar file.

Step2: Created a source folder in my project

```
src/main/antlr4
```

Inside this I created the package

```
com.helper.tony.grammar
```

I placed my Java.g4 file inside this package. This was done to create my Visitors and Listeners with the same package structure in the output directory. Output directory location is

```
target/generated-sources/antlr4
```

as indicated by output directory tag in pom.xml.
I also added this into my build path.

Step3: Setting pom file properly.I added  tag into my pom file and did set maven compiler plugin source and target version to Java 1.8.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.helper.mani</groupId>
<artifactId>builder_factory</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
        <version>4.6</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
            <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <grammars>Java.g4</grammars>
                <visitor>true</visitor>
                <listener>true</listener>
                <inputEncoding>UTF-8</inputEncoding>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/antlr4</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>antlr4</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Step4: Executed the following maven goal to generate Visitor and Listener classes.

```
org.antlr:antlr4-maven-plugin:4.6:antlr4
```

With all the files in place, I was able to write my parser easily.

```
EuReKA!!!
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I found it because I had the same problem. I re-generated my parser class while making sure the '-visitor' switch was in the command line. Dropping *only* the parser class into the existing project fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

By default, ANTLR generates listeners and does not generate visitors.

If you are using the ANTLR 4 tool in Eclipse, you should open Project properties, select ANTLR 4 / Tool and check the "Generate parse tree visitors (-visitor)" option. You may need to touch (edit) the grammar file to force the ANTLR 4 tool to re-generate the sources.

If you use maven, you should explicitly enable visitor generation:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${antlr.version}</version>
  <configuration>
      <listener>false</listener>
      <visitor>true</visitor>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
      <execution>
          <goals>
              <goal>antlr4</goal>
          </goals>
      </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```